# logging.handler.TimedRotatingFileHandler never rotates the log

Tags: python, logging, log-rotation

A have a script which synchronizes time on linux servers( CentOS 6) and writes offset in log. I want to make after 10 days the current log (ntp.log) copy to old (ntp.log-date), but this does not work. The script continues to write into one file and not rotating. It is run by cron every 5 minutes. I using python version 2.6. I specifically set the interval in seconds to check. What am i doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import ntplib
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
from time import ctime
import os
import socket

hostname = socket.gethostname()
logHandler = TimedRotatingFileHandler('/root/ntp/log/ntp.log', when='S', interval=300)
logFormatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
logHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
logger.addHandler(logHandler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


c = ntplib.NTPClient()
response = c.request('1.rhel.pool.ntp.org')
logger.info('| %s time offset is | %s' % (hostname, response.offset))
datestr = ctime(response.tx_time)
os.system('date -s "%s"' % datestr)
```

Comment: I'd strongly advise using `ntpd` and `logrotate` rather than reinventing the wheel. `ntpd`'s logic is much more sound than periodic one-time "synchronizations".

Comment: about `logrotate` must see, and i can't use `ntpd`, i need synchronization' logs

Comment: `ntpd` works much smarter than just "synchronizations", it uses the "kernel time discipline" API and is designed to actually *make you forget about the synchronization stuff once and for all* (http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/discipline.html#house : "If left running continuously, an NTP client on a fast LAN in a home or office environment can maintain synchronization nominally within one millisecond.") Don't worry, it logs it whenever it does anything with the system clock.

Comment: i need custom logging, because it using in web application

Comment: Do you expect me to buy this as an excuse? I assure you, you won't manage to synchronize better than `ntpd` does. And if you don't *need* to sync regularly, why do you need to *report* it regularly? If you have to report *something*, then look closely at what *exactly* you're expected to report - and deduce a way to produce it without sacrificing the actual work.

Comment: Btw, if you're still not convinced, here's the flaw in your algorithm: `response.tx_time` ([Transmit timestamp](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1305)) is the time the received packet left the server. The time frame between its departure and `date` calling [`stime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stime) is unaccounted for.

Answer (score 4):

Leaving outside the fact your algorithm is plain incorrect, i'll answer the question regarding the logging issue.

Here's the related `logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler` logic:

```
def __init__(<...>):
    <...>
    if self.when == 'S':
        self.interval = 1 # one second
    <...>
    self.interval = self.interval * interval # multiply by units requested
    <...>
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        t = os.stat(filename)[ST_MTIME]
    else:
        t = int(time.time())
    self.rolloverAt = self.computeRollover(t)

def computeRollover(self, currentTime):
    result = currentTime + self.interval
    <special logic that doesn't apply in your case>
    return result
```

So, the rollover time in `'S'` mode is computed from the file's [*mtime*](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) at the time of your script's init. *mtime* is modified each time you write to the file.

Thus, the rollover would only be done if you log after `interval` seconds since your script's start. Which is never the case since it runs for much less.

Possible fixes:

- make the script run for that long, e.g. with an infinite loop as you suggested. If it's to run indefinitely, it should probably be made a daemon
- change the rollover moment calculation algorithm

  - this is not possible with the stock logic (the "special logic" in `TimedRotatingFileHandler.computeRollover()` only applies to `'MIDNIGHT'` and `'Wn'` cases), so you need to replace your handler's `computeRollover()`
  - basically, you need to set the rollover time to the next "reference moment" after the current file's *mtime*.

Comment: Please tell me what I need to change to the algorithm worked like I need?

Comment: Maybe i must run it not through cron and make infinite loop. Or I simply must increase interval?

Comment: The infinite loop will work. I'll now look if other handler parameters will as well.

Answer (score 2):

This may help you (rolling over the log if the log has been created in multiples of 10th day and the log last modified a day before)

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
import ntplib
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
from time import ctime
import os
import socket

hostname = socket.gethostname()
logHandler = TimedRotatingFileHandler('/root/ntp/log/ntp.log', when='D', interval=10)
logFormatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
logHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
#Get File creation Time
log_ctime = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime("/root/ntp/log/ntp.log")).date()
log_mtime = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime("/root/ntp/log/ntp.log")).date()
delta_c = datetime.now().date() - log_ctime 
delta_m = datetime.now().date() - log_mtime 
if delta_c.days %10 == 0 and delta_m.days>=1:
   logHandler.doRollover()
logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
logger.addHandler(logHandler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


c = ntplib.NTPClient()
response = c.request('1.rhel.pool.ntp.org')
logger.info('| %s time offset is | %s' % (hostname, response.offset))
datestr = ctime(response.tx_time)
os.system('date -s "%s"' % datestr)
```